# create a circle on a link between nodes on click event in d3

Tags: d3.js

Want to add a circle on the links between nodes on click and I should be able to attach a drag event to the circle so that when I drag a circle, the link should move to . where I am going wrong in this?

```
var dragCircle = d3.behavior.drag()
      .on('dragstart', function(){
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  })
      .on('drag', function(d,i){
        var x = d3.event.x;
        var y = d3.event.y;
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
      });   

//I want to attach circle to the link so that when I drag circle, line should move too.
function drawCircle(x, y, size) {
svg.selectAll(".edge").append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'linkcirc')
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .attr("r", size)
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .call(dragCircle);

}


//catching the mouse position to decide to place the circle
edge.on("click",function() {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    drawCircle(coords[0], coords[1],3);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

SVG will not allow you to create a circle as a child of a line (and your code is creating one circle for every link on every click). Instead of this:

```
svg.selectAll(".edge").append("circle") # appends one circle to each edge
```

Try this:

```
svg.append("circle") # appends a single circle to the SVG image
```

After changing your fiddle accordingly I was able to fire the drag event, but it still needs work. Using the drag behaviour you probably want to look at the `event.dx` and `event.dy` values rather than the absolute values, and you can simply change the circle's `cx` and `cy` instead of applying a translation (if that's easier). See https://jsfiddle.net/pzej8tkq/3/ for ideas.

Comment: Good catch. Sometimes people don't believe you when you explain this child/parent rule, replying "but I'm seeing the element in the DOM tree"...

Comment: my requirement is ..whenever i click on a link,it should add a circle to the line at that point and i should be able to drag the link from that point.(its like breaking a link at the circle)

Comment: *"my requirement is"*... This is not a free code writing service! At least be civil and thanks  Owen for finding one (major) problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks owen..Sry! I somehow missed to mention that. and thanks Gereado for pointing out...I was not rude to mention that "my req". I thouht this site helps ppl who got stuck in between.I am not asking for free code for kind info..

Comment: Please build on the code provided and, if you need further assistance, update your question. Maybe see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795 for some ideas.

Comment: No worries @user3196985. SO is about coders helping coders but, above all, is about creating a knowledge base. You should acknowledge Owen's answer because in the future, if someone makes the same mistake you did, it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks owen. I will. I am very new to D3 and i am just trying to get hold of it.